# Two if statements using ternary condition

Tags: php, ternary

The title seems confusing but this is my first time using ternary conditions. I've read that ternary is meant to be used to make an inline if/else statement. Using no else is not possible. Is it true?

I want to change this with ternary condition for practice

```
if (isset($_SESSION['group']
{
if ($_SESSION['item'] == 'A')
{
echo "Right!";
}
}
```

It has two if statements only. The second if is nested with the other. I've also read that to make a no else possible for ternary, it just have to be set to null or empty string.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @Frank Schmitt: That looks like (malformed) PHP.

Comment: Sorry, ternary conditional operators are not the right thing to use here. Stick with if statements, but use `&&` instead of nesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bad example because you can use an AND-operator on the nested if:

```
$result = isset($_SESSION['group'] && $_SESSION['item'] == 'A' ? true : false;
```

Of course you can nest ternary operator, too:

```
$result = isset($_SESSION['group'] ? ( $_SESSION['item'] == 'A' ? true : false ) : false;
```

with echo

```
echo  isset($_SESSION['group'] ? ( $_SESSION['item'] == 'A' ? "Right!" : "false" ) : "false";
```

Comment: You might as well do `$result = isset($_SESSION['group']) && $_SESSION['item'] == 'A';`

Comment: user: <?php echo (isset($_SESSION["errors"]) && $_SESSION["country"] == "Afghanistan" ? "SELECTED" : "") ?>

Answer (score 5):

```
echo (isset($_SESSION['group']) && $_SESSION['item'] == 'A') ? "Right" : ""
```

Better still (readable, maintainable), use:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['group']) && $_SESSION['item'] == 'A')
{
   echo "Right!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
isset($_SESSION['group'] ? (if ($_SESSION['item'] == 'A') ? echo "Right" : null) : null
```

Try this, I think it might work =].

For further reading on ternary conditions in Java/ whatever you're using look at http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: Nope, `echo` has to be outside.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest two ternary statements as this example:

```
echo (isset($_SESSION['group']))?($_SESSION['item']== 'A')?'Right!':null:null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can do this as well? `(isset($_SESSION['group']) && ($_SESSION['item']=='A')) &&($result$c= 1);` or `echo (isset($_SESSION['group']) && ($_SESSION['item']=='A')) ? 'Hello!':'World!';`